# Backgrid integration

Tags: javascript, marionette, backgrid

How I would use backgrid within a backbone.marionette application?

Answer (score 10):

It's as simple as it looks.  Just add the Backgrid view to any region:

```
MyApp.addRegions({
  someRegion: "#some-div"
});

var columns ....
var userList ....

MyApp.someRegion.show(
    new Backgrid.Grid({
        columns : columns,
        collection : userList
    })
);
```