# backgrid with backbone marionette js integration

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backgrid

i am trying to integrate [backgrid.js](http://backgridjs.com/) with [backbone.marionette.js](http://marionettejs.com/).

I am able to create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meetantoalphi/WQ9wB/) some how but don't really know how to integrate this with backbone.marionette.js.

Hopefully some SO people can help me to do that who have already done this.

I am very new to `backbone.js` and `marionette.js`.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this might help others also.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790906/backgrid-integration)  is the answer i found which helped me.

Best Regards and Thanks to SO